# Using result from jedis transaction response before executing transaction

Tags: redis, nosql, jedis

Suppose I have a transaction t. I want to get something from the database that would have been inserted previously in this transaction and use that value in a subsequent operation in the same transaction as so:

```
byte[] data = t.get(key).get();
t.set(other_key, data);
```

However in Jedis, when I try this, I get a JedisDataException telling me that I need to execute the transaction before calling get() on the transaction response. Is there a way that I can use the result from the query in the same transaction without executing it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't with Redis transaction. Redis's transaction is basically you send all the commands to Redis in one go, Redis executes these commands while commands from other connections wait for it to finish. After it finishes, it returns the results for you. Note, it doesn't return the result to you in the middle of the transaction, unlike MySQL. So you can't read the result of a query in the middle.

To do what you want, you'll need Lua Script( it takes about ten minutes to learn to write what you were asking for), it operates on the server side(doesn't need to return the result to the client in the middle of an operation).

You might want to read these

[Redis Transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions)

[Redis Lua Script](https://www.compose.com/articles/a-quick-guide-to-redis-lua-scripting/)